# Event keeps being handled despite of off() being invoked

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, d3.js

I want all my events stop executing on the chart when it's clicked. However, despite my wishes, the darn handlers get executed anyway. I suspect that I target a different element than what I intend to. Beats me how, though.

As [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chamster/gb8af03m/) exemplifies, clicking any sector makes the ring go green. Then, I want the legend texts not to re-appear upon existing the remaining ring area.

```
var grx = chart.selectAll(".sector").data(pie(dataPoints))
  .enter().append("g").attr("class", "sector")
  .on("mouseenter", function (target) {
    $(".legendMain").animate({ opacity: 0 }, { queue: false });
  })
  .on("mouseleave", function () {
    $(".legendMain").animate({ opacity: 1 }, { queue: false });
  })
  .on("click", function (target) {
    $("#chart .sector path").css("fill", "rgb(0,111,0)");
    d3.selectAll("#chart .sector path")
      .transition().duration(1000).attr("d", out);

    //d3.selectAll("#chart .sector text").remove();
    $(".sector").off();
    $("path").off();
    $("g").off();
  });
```

I've tried turning it off for *g*s, *path*s and *text*s ans well as all *.sector* class elements. Nothing helps. Am I selecting the wrong components? How do I check who's holding the event handlers? Does the handling get stuck because of the data binding under D3?

I'm pretty sure there's something weird in there - or at least highly contra-intuitive - because I've tried doing the following and the events still take place (the texts are fading in/out).

```
$("*").off();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing `d3` and `jquery` event binding.  If you create a d3 event handler with `selection.on`, the proper way to remove it is:

```
d3.selectAll(".sector").on('mouseenter', null);
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gb8af03m/23/).

Comment: Is there a way to turn off multiple/all events in a single whack? Is there an API for that? I haven't seen much in the docs of that...

Comment: @KonradViltersten, it looks like [it was discussed](https://github.com/d3/d3/pull/1855) but never implemented.  It seems you could namespace all your events and then remove them all by namespace.